# Ho to properly use C# form.Location property

Tags: c#, forms

I created a C# windows form which I want to position on my second monitor.
I tried to set the form.Location property prior to showing the form but that did not work.
I noticed that  when I set the Location only once, it is not being set - see the image I attached.
However even when I set it twice and, in the debugger I see the location is set, the form does not open when I want it to.

```
    var form = new ConfigurationForm(vaProxy);
    var location = new Point(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.X + 1000,500);
    form.Location = location;
    form.Location = location;
    form.ShowDialog();
```

[![form.Location not set][1]][1]
[![location IS set][2]][2]

I also tried to use:
`this.Location` inside the form itself but that did not work either.

So how do I open the form in the right location or move it to it once it is open?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUAp.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcEcM.png

Comment: Note, you appear to be assuming that screens will always be "1 on the left, 2 on the right". This isn't the case. Windows allows screen positioning anywhere. It would be better to get the location of the secondary screen and base off that, than to get the primary screen location and offset a fixed amount of right and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ConfigurationForm, in the properties grid, set `StartupPosition = Manual` or do the same in code (`form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`) before you show it